# If $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$ so$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b^2+c^2}\geq2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$. Prove that:
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{c^3}{d^2+a^2}+\frac{d^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq2$$
I tried C-S, but without success.

Comment: i think it is $d^2+a^2$. I tried to edit post but couldnt

Comment: @Markoff Chainz I fixed my post. Thank you!