# Given $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd=1$

Tags: inequality

Given $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd=1$. Prove that $\frac{a^3}{b^2(c^2+d^2)}+\frac{b^3}{c^2(d^2+a^2)}+\frac{c^3}{d^2(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{d^3}{a^2(b^2+c^2)}\geq 2$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics.SE! In general, people are more helpful if you provide evidence that you have attempted to solve the problem, something along the lines of "I tried so and so", or any ideas you might have.

Comment: Have to wonder, is this related to [that other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125707/if-a2b2c2d2-4-so-sum-limits-cyc-fraca3b2c2-geq2)?

Comment: What is the source of this question ??

Comment: @Nirbhay : It from my friend.

I tried C-S inequality, but without success :(

Comment: @Analyn_a Hey, I realized that AM-GM is enough to prove the inequality. I'll soon post my answer.. :)

Comment: @Analyn_a I have posted my answer. See if that helps you. If yes, then please accept my answer. :)

Comment: @Nirbhay: where is your answer?